# How to get SFDC Lead Object Views in my Android application, I am using REST Api but there is no class called ApexPage.StandardSetController

Tags: android

How to get `SFDC` Lead Object Views in my Android application.
I am using **REST Api** but there is no class called `ApexPage.StandardSetController`.